# OpenShift template with the jboss/wildfly docker image that deploys my war (binary source strategy)

Tags: java, docker, openshift, wildfly

In my OpenShift template, I have this BuildConfig:

```
  - kind: BuildConfig
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: "webapp-build"
    spec:
      triggers:
        - type: ImageChange
      source:
        type: Binary
      strategy:
        sourceStrategy:
          from:
            kind: DockerImage
            name: jboss/wildfly:11.0.0.Final
      output:
        to:
          kind: ImageStreamTag
          name: "webapp-image:latest"
      resources:
        limits:
          cpu: 1
          memory: 1Gi
```

Which I call with:

```
oc start-build "webapp-build" --from-file=target/ROOT.war
```

But I get this error on OpenShift Dedicated:

```
Pulling image "jboss/wildfly:11.0.0.Final" ...
error: build error: image "jboss/wildfly:11.0.0.Final" must specify a user that is numeric and within the range of allowed users
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using a non s2i image for a sourceStrategy build. The reason you are getting the error is because the image specifies a non-numeric user.

```
$ docker inspect docker.io/jboss/wildfly:11.0.0.Final | jq '.[] | .Config.User'
"jboss"
```

This raises an error in the [IsUserAllowed](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image/blob/e7eaf99faf66a61208fbe2aca690a52b725db766/pkg/util/user/rangelist.go#L78) check performed prior to an s2i (sourceStrategy) build starts.

If I am understanding your need correct, **you might be looking for the [s2i-wildfly image](https://github.com/openshift-s2i/s2i-wildfly) for your build**. The `jboss/wildfly` images are runtime images not intended for s2i use (ie. there are no s2i scripts). So use this `sourceStrategy` instead:

```
    sourceStrategy:
      from:
        kind: DockerImage
        # Uses WildFly 11.0
        name: "openshift/wildfly-110-centos7:latest"
```

Alternatively, if you really want to use that particular image, you can do so by doing the following.

1. Create a new image with user configured correct and use this from the `ImageStreamTag` instead of the `DockerImage` in your build config. `oc new-build -D $'FROM docker.io/jboss/wildfly:11.0.0.Final\nUSER 1001' --to=wildfly:latest`.
2. [Specify scripts url parameter](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.9/dev_guide/builds/build_strategies.html#override-builder-image-scripts) in your `sourceStrategy` configuration. The expectation here is that these scripts know what to do with your binary artifact.

Comment: "openshift/wildfly-110-centos7:latest" works like a charm, thanks!